# talend datetime format parse from string

Tags: parsing, datetime, formatting, talend

I am trying to parse a date that is formatted "2014-09-30T13:32:19+02:00" from xml to postgres table
I am getting an error unparsable date if I set format to TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",row1.time) when I try to parse it from string
or if i set the input filed is of type date I get the same error.

Any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone

Comment: If you're not actually using the date as a date object or modifying it in your Talend job then you're nearly always better off to just handle it as a string throughout and pass it to your database as such and have it implicitly convert the string to the date type the field is expecting.